# Running cookiecutter django on an intranet

Tags: django, docker, caddy, cookiecutter-django

Now that Caddy has been adopted which comes by default setup for https and requires the domain name to be routable from the internet. What is the proper setup to run on an intranet with only http without access from the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To serve internal hostnames without HTTPS, you can disable HTTPS by specifying HTTP specifically:

```
http://internal
...
# rest of your Caddyfile goes here
```